# Elastic Search Scroll API rolling in an infinite loop

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I was trying to fetch data based on batches. For this have written below piece of code

```
final Scroll scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(1L));
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder().query(boolQuery)
                    .sort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.DESC).size(10000);

SearchRequest req = new SearchRequest("logs");
req.scroll(scroll);
req.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(req, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
SearchHit[] resultsHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
logger.info("scrollId:{}",scrollId);
while (resultsHits != null && resultsHits.length > 0) {
   SearchScrollRequest searchScrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId);
   searchScrollRequest.scroll(scroll);
   SearchResponse response = client.scroll(searchScrollRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
   scrollId = response.getScrollId();
   resultsHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();

   logger.info("scrollId:{}",scrollId);
   logger.info("resultHits:{}",resultsHits.length);
 }
```

But above code is running in an infinite loop. Don't understand what i am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `searchResponse` inside your `while` loop instead of using `response` from `SearchResponse response = client.scroll(searchScrollRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);`
 that's is why you are running in an infinite loop.

Change to:

```
SearchResponse response = client.scroll(searchScrollRequest,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
scrollId = response.getScrollId();
resultsHits = response.getHits().getHits();
```

Hope this helps